# How to call a javascript function when a button inside html table is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

update sir anmarti
hello sir thank you for answering my questions
i add this code to

page_load

```
string eventTarget = this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
        if (eventTarget == "DeleteRecord")
        {
            Label1.Text = "Method called!!!";
            // Delete your record here
        }else
        {
            Label1.Text = "No method";
        }
```

on page load(run time) the label1 change its text to "No method"

then i clicked the button then the pop up comes in. i choosed the YES button but nothing happend it didn't even close the pop up

in order to check if the javascript works correctly i changed this code
__doPostBack("DeleteRecord", '');
to
$("[id*=btnadd]").click();

and after clicking the yes button of pop up it clicked the button BTNADD

my question sir is why do   __doPostBack("DeleteRecord", ''); doesn't work on me? i even tried some posted tutorials online but its still the same

---

This is the javascript function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       //$("[id*=btnDelete]").removeAttr("onclick");
       $("[id*=btnDelete]").removeAttr("onclick");
       $("#dialog").dialog({
           modal: true,
           autoOpen: false,
           title: "Confirmation",
           width: 350,
           height: 160,
           buttons: [
           {
               id: "Yes",
               text: "Yes",
               click: function () {
                   $("[id*=btnDelete]").attr("rel", "delete");
                   $("[id*=btnDelete]").click();
               }
           },
           {
               id: "No",
               text: "No",
               click: function () {
                   $(this).dialog('close');
               }
           }
           ]
       });
       $("[id*=btnDelete]").click(function () {
           if ($(this).attr("rel") != "delete") {
               $('#dialog').dialog('open');
               return false;
           } else {
               __doPostBack(this.name, '');
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Here is the code behind

```
    protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record Deleted.')", true);
    }
```

Html code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteRecord" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
       Do you want to delete this record?
    </div>
```

it works perfectly

but how to i call the function inside html table

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "signatoryid") %> 
   </td>
   <td>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "signatoryname") %> 
   </td>
   <td>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "signatoryPosition") %> 
   </td>
   <td>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "signatoryOffice") %> 
   </td>
   <td>
      <button type="button" class="btndelete btn btn-xs btn-danger" OnClick="DeleteRecord">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>Delete
      </button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Client side**

Create a function that opens the dialog and call it in the `onClick` event:

```
 <button type="button" class="btndelete btn btn-xs btn-danger" OnClick="javascript:deleteRecord();">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>Delete
  </button>


<script>
  $(function () {
     $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Confirmation",
        width: 350,
        height: 160,
        buttons: [
        {
            id: "Yes",
            text: "Yes",
            click: function () {
                 __doPostBack("DeleteRecord", '');
            }
        },
        {
            id: "No",
            text: "No",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        }
        ]
     });
});

    function deleteRecord(){
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    }
 </script>
```

**Server side code**

If you do a hand-made `__doPostback()` you have to retrieve the `EventTarget` and `EventArguments` (if you have) on the `Page_Load()` or `Page_Init()` if you prefer, event handlers of the current page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string eventTarget = this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
      if(eventTarget == "DeleteRecord")
      {

       // Delete your record here
      }

  }
```

Comment: thanks it's working but i don't understand the server side code you posted
can you give me a sample code sir that calls a code behind function when the yes button is clicked. thank you

Comment: `__doPostBack("DeleteRecord", '');` should hit the `Page_Load()` event handler.

Comment: can you explain sir? the code. i really don't understand it. or can you give me a keyword to search for me to read? to understand better the code? thank you

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361950/how-to-use-dopostback-function-in-asp-net) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function) and also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: hello sir @anmarti i updated my questions above hope you can help me. my question is not enough in this box to i put it above thank you

Comment: It worked for me. Download this VS2013 [Solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/131jarbygmccj9g/WebApplication2.zip?dl=0) and test it. Select `Default.aspx` -> View in Browser

Comment: sir anmarti, im using the latest version and it doesn't work for me. so what i did is to use PageMethods and it worked. thank you for you're time sir