# UpdatePanel postback removes changes made using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, autopostback

I am using ASP.NET UpdatePanel for partial postback. Somehow after the server side postback  (ddl_SelectedIndexChanged), the value set by a Javascript function (lblTotal's value of 100) gets removed.  Is there anyway to preserve value set by the Javascript function?

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculateTotal() {
        var lblTotal = document.getElementById("<%= lblTotal.ClientID%>");
        lblTotal.innerHTML = "100";
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateGrid" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnTextChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"             AutoPostBack="true"  />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkLevels" runat="server" onclick="calculateTotal()"  />
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" />
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# / Code Behind:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here is that when you change data with `calculateTotal` in Javascript, server does not know about changes since you don't post back data to server.

So you need to trigger the postback event with `__doPostBack()`:

Client side:

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var lblTotal = document.getElementById("<%= lblTotal.ClientID%>");
    //Calculation
    var totalValue = "100";

    __doPostBack('chkLevels', totalValue);
}
```

`Page_Load` on Server side :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "chkLevels")
    {
        var totalValue = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        lblTotal.Text = totalValue;
    }

}
```

See: [how to use __doPostBack function in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361950/how-to-use-dopostback-function-in-asp-net)